# Ubuntu 14.10 dual monitors not working (display port & VGA)

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, intel

```
$ lspci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: 
Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I'm attempting to run 2 monitors but only one is working.

The VGA output is working and under **System Settings -> Display**,
my second monitor (display port) shows up and is recognized, but the monitor is displaying a no signal light.

Are two monitors even supported with this graphics card? If so how can I get my second monitor to work?

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with your drivers.
Open the dash and search for `Proprietary Driver` and see if you have to update your drivers for the Intel Graphics card